# How to use HTML <picture> tag with Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

How can i use the `<picture>` Tag with Tailwind CSS? Or more specifically, how can I use Tailwind's media queries in it?

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can style the `<picture>` and the `<img>` elements like other HTML elements, by adding the `class` attribute. To target specific breakpoints, prefix your classes with `sm:` etc. as you normally would.

```html
<picture class=""> <!-- Add Tailwind classes here -->
  <source media="" srcset="">
  <source media="" srcset="">
  <img src="" alt="" class="sm:w-auto"> <!-- Add Tailwind classes here -->
</picture>
```

Styling the `<picture>` element will style the image container, while classes on the `<img>` element will affect the image directly.

Comment: I think for me I'd want the question how do you convert the breakpoints to tailwinds sizes? ```<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:md)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:sm)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture> ```